# How do i align the logo with nav?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I have a problem. I'm working on responsive design and where I have a `media screen` of `min-width 860px`. I want my navigation text to be next to my logo. I managed to do this, but the navigation text is placed on top of my line instead of in the center.

(hope that makes sense)[image]

```css
.netflix-logo {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 18px;
}
nav a {
  display:inline;
  vertical-align: middle;  
  color: white;
  margin: 9px 8px 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I tried working with `vertical-align: middle` and center but that didn't work either, could you please help me?

Comment: Kindly upload the html also so, it will be more easy to understand and solve the problem

Comment: Use flexbox provide us more code for us to be able to provide a better answer please.

Answer (score 2):

You could use flexbox for that. Just put both of these elements in one container and all the previous styles which you used for positioning on `.netflix-logo && nav a` can be deleted. Flexbox will do everything itself.

```css
.netflix-container {
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center
   align-items:center
}
```

P.S.: I strongly recommend you to read more about [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), it's an awesome tool for creating responsive designs.

Here are some guides:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: +1 for this, I also created a codepen for you to see the html,css and flexbox being used to align them 'center' https://codepen.io/shane-muirhead/pen/PoabwJK


EDIT: float: left and right are such old ways to achieve certain layout. Strongly advise flexbox or css grid for more modern and advanced layouts.

Answer (score 0):

you can use display flex for layouts instead of floating.

if you need more information you can read here - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

if you have doubts you can post your code to help